Why recordTypeVisibilities is an empty array in response to /services/data/{version}/tooling/sobjects/Profile/{profile.id}
I have configured several RecordTypes for Account entity and those show up under certain profile:

I am using super user when placing a call:
/services/data/{version}/tooling/sobjects/Profile/{profile.id}
My super user has CustomizeApplication, ViewSetup permissions.
Why the heck there are no items under "recordTypeVisibilities": [] ?
What am I missing?
